# What database should I use to deploy a WPF application?

Tags: sql, wpf, database, windows, installation

What database should I use?

I am currently under the design phase of a WPF application. I have never deployed an application before and I am not sure what database I should use. I want my application to be deployable on any Window's 7 machine without the need of a special install (i.e. SQL Server). I don't want to be in the deployment phase and find out that I should have used another database. Can I simply run a SQL script on the install to generate all the tables and fields required for the software to properly run? Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is for a distributed install not a network install...e.g. You won't be installing in a corporate environment with a central sql server?

Comment: Just a distributed install. I.e. Something you could buy at a store and install on your home machine. @Charleh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLCE fits the bill, (and there are probably others as well); small footprint, file-based and just one (or very few) extra DLL's to include in your app. Personally I wouldn't use it for  anything other than a smal, single-user app, but if yours is single user and the amount of data is small, you could do worse.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for! @E.J. Brennan

Comment: Okay so I just tried to add SQLCE to my solution and I received this error. (The version of the Microsoft SQL Server Compact database that you are adding to the project is not supported by the project type. The database will be added to the project, but data tools such as the Dataset Designer will not work with this database.) Is SQLCE only enabled for web projects? @E.J. Brennan

Comment: Don't know what the error is, but you definitely are not limited to only web apps; I've used it for desktop apps in the past.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not use too complex queries, you can use sqllite
[Here you can find it and c# connector here](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have decided to go with SQLITE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a WPF app with no plans beyond the next few years, SQL CE will be fine and will work well.

But if you are thinking about compatibility with (or a transition to) a potential Windows 8 Metro version of your app (in which SQL CE is not supported), or another OS (e.g. OS X), you should consider SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have decided to go with SQLITE.